# MySQL: Find records matching in two tables A & B where B is massive

Tags: mysql

The following works fine but is too slow . I just need to know that there are matching records in the Table B so is there any trick?

(curiously the opposite search: find records that don't join (IS NULL) is very quick)

```
SELECT
  TableA.id
FROM
  TableA
  LEFT JOIN
    TableB 
  ON
    TableB.TableA_id = TableA.id
WHERE
  TableB.id IS NOT NULL and TableA.clientid=13 ;
```

Clientid is now indexed but it is this subclause which drastically slows the query from very quick to minutes.

(03May12 I have now tried this same query on an identical database on a much more powerful server and the query takes a second. So it would seem my problem is that my original server is totally overloaded , ironically the above query was being used to identify records which we could delete to reduce the size of the tables. I will have to re-build the database on a faster server , clean it up and then regenerate it on the "slow" server)

Comment: do you have any indexes on your tables?

Comment: Do you have a `FOREIGN KEY` properly defined on `TableB.TableA_id`? That would provide an index which would improve performance. (we assume `TableA.id` is a PK and therefore indexed already)

Comment: ...like `FOREIGN KEY (TableA_id) REFERENCES TableA (id)`

Comment: The query above is correctly indexed. But Guilty confession I had an extra clause in the Where (which I didn't think relevant to this discussion) which referenced a column which wasn't indexed.

Answer (score 2):

index are supposed to be created on TableB.TableA_id and TableA.id

```
SELECT
  Count(TableA.id)
FROM
  TableA
  JOIN
    TableB 
  ON
        TableB.TableA_id = TableA.id And TableB.id IS NOT NULL
and TableA.clientid=13 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query finds all records from A that are also in B:

```
SELECT TableA.id
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableB.TableA_id = TableA.id
```

It will perform well if there's an index on `TableB.TableA_id` (index on `TableA.id` is irrelevant to performance of this query)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT TableA.id
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.TableA_id = TableA.id
```

In this case you dont need to use not null because of inner join. hope this would be better solution